# What control panel setting will control the windows menu font size?

Tags: windows, windows-10, fonts, control-panel

I have two PCs on which I have windows 10 installed and the menu font size on the two is slightly different. 
[image]
I don't recollect having changed any of the default settings windows came with. As I work across this home and work PC, the different font size is a bit irritating.

Comment: Compare screen resolution on both PCs.

Comment: @JosefZ Yes the screen resolutions are different (left 1440 X 900, right 1600 X 900), but I am doing remote desktop from one to the other and even in this case, they appear in different sizes (Just in case you thought that pixel size may be playing the spoiler).